# Experience Editor Editing is disabled

Tags: experience-editor

I have done something to my environment - In the experience editor, "Editing" and "Designing" check boxes are greyed out, so I cant actually edit anything. Is ExperienceEditor.Enabled a setting somewhere?[image]

This is Sitecore 8.2 Update 3

**UPDATE**

Here is the sites section of my showconfig:

```
<sites>
    <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableTracking="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="15MB" viewStateCacheSize="1MB" xslCacheSize="25MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" contentLanguage="en" patch:source="Delphic.LanguageFallback.config" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity" itemwebapi.access="ReadWrite" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" enableItemLanguageFallback="true"/>
    <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableTracking="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" language="en" patch:source="Sitecore.DefaultLanguage.config"/>
    <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx"/>
    <site name="service" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service"/>
    <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
    <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true"/>
    <site name="MySiteDotCom" hostName="local.mysite.com" errorpageid="26B66A89-8A83-4CD5-80C9-0200F0C7754F" sitesettingsid="FD867206-CB41-4A4E-8C61-C965BD74F5E4" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/MySite DotCom/home" domain="default" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" patch:source="Delphic.LanguageFallback.config" database="master" filterItems="true" enableWorkflow="true" enableItemLanguageFallback="true"/>
    <site name="MySiteDotNet" hostName="local.mysite.net" errorpageid="9CAA474A-F4F0-4462-A3F3-038B6B3F671D" sitesettingsid="CEC6BC86-5A07-4020-84B0-0A7F2D936664" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/MySite Prepaid DotNet/home" domain="default" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" patch:source="Delphic.LanguageFallback.config" database="master" filterItems="true" enableWorkflow="true" enableItemLanguageFallback="true"/>
    <!--
     ITEM WEB API SETTINGS FOR A SITE
       Supported attributes (first is default):
         itemwebapi.mode: [Off|StandardSecurity|AdvancedSecurity]
           If set to Off, Item Web API is turned off.
           If set to StandardSecurity, Item Web API is turned on. Default Sitecore security model is used.
           If set to AdvancedSecurity, Item Web API is turned on. Default Sitecore security model is extended with a requirement to explicitely set the 'remote:fieldread' access right for content fields.
         itemwebapi.access: [ReadOnly|ReadWrite]
           If set to ReadOnly, then only READ operation is allowed.
           If set to ReadWrite, then CREATE, READ, UPDATE, and DELETE operations are allowed.
         itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess: [false|true].
           Defines if access is allowed for non-authenticated user.

    -->
    <site name="website" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" language="en" patch:source="Sitecore.LanguageFallback.config" itemwebapi.mode="Off" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false"/>
    <site name="scheduler" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
    <site name="system" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
    <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableTracking="false" enableWorkflow="true"/>
</sites>
```

Comment: 1) Are you logged in as an .IsAdministrator user?  2) Does the "site" you are on have Experience Editing enabled?

Comment: 1) Yes, I am in as 'admin' 2) How would I enable/disable this?

Comment: enableWebEdit="true" on the <site> definition item

Comment: Yes, enableWebEdit is true

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your `<sitecore><sites/></sitecore>` configuration?

Comment: Try to check your Commands.config file and make sure you have the appropriate "webedit:toggleeditvisibility", etc. commands in there.

Comment: I dont have any webedit:togglevisibility commands, but when I look at a clean install version of commands.config, its not there either

Comment: You could check the core db and see if something with permissions was changed on the items (or the panel item) there that would impact these permissions.

Comment: 1 Open developer tools and find request containg ExperienceEditor.EditMode.CanEdit . Check response for anything else then json object. 2 check your logs

Comment: @wiero Can you add that as an answer - it indirectly pointed me to the solution

Comment: I think you should add an answer describing your solution. I had this situation once with custom headers in web.config and SXA. I would really love to hear about your case. As to my comment it was just a tip, not a proper se answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@wiero pointed me in the right direction...

When I selected any of the ExperienceEditor.EditMode items in the network tab of my browser developer tools, I saw that the error returned was about editing Cookies after the page had loaded, or something similar. It turned out this was something I had done. For very long and convoluted reasons, I am removing the session cookie, to prevent session blocking:

http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/

But really, I only needed this in the CDs. Having it on the CM broke the Experience Editor. After removing it, everything worked fine.

Comment: I wrote small blog post on potential ways to make this kind of situations more visible http://tomekwie.azurewebsites.net/2017/10/30/experience-editor-enhancement/ (I didn't test this in production environment )

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem where I wasn't able to enable editing nor adding a component on a page.
After further inspection of the network requests, all SPEAK requests were - in my case - blocked because they had no file extension.

To resolve this issue, I had to edit the web.config and allow empty file extensions:
Add this fileExtensions to the :

```
<fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
    <remove fileExtension="." />
    <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
</fileExtensions>
```