# Experience Editor disabled on local machine

Tags: experience-editor

I am facing a weird issue where experience editor (sitecore 9) is not getting enabled on my local system while it works fine on all the dev environment as well as other developers machine.
I have checked the console and there is no error in the console or networking tab. Also, I am logged in as administrator and have verified the config files with enable webedit set to true. Is there any thing I am missing?

Comment: is experience editor showing loading? is it not able to add components?

Comment: yes, i am getting the same screen as https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/experience-editor-editing-is-disabled

Comment: Have you been logging as Admin? That could a security role issue.

Comment: yes, as i mentioned in the issue, i am logged in as administrator, one thing to add, i am using a self signed certificate

Comment: Are there placeholders in the page presentation and are there allowed controls for the placeholders on the page?

Comment: yes, the same is working for other developers on their local but not for me, i can see the text for placeholder as well but nothing is clickable and the button to add component is disabled

Comment: Did you check your logs is there any error in logs??

Comment: I was making multiple changes and now i can see below warning in browser console                                                             
                16295462682458532383.js:7194 SessionTimeout not found in settings scForm.Settings
scSitecore.onLoad @ 16295462682458532383.js:7194
jquery-2.1.1.js:8554 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.